# Weigh Sphinx Results By Date

Tags: php, sql, search, sphinx

I am using [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/) on a website to keep track of various table entries. These entries contain a date component and are less relevant after their data has been passed.

How can I have Sphinx assign more weight to results that match the search criteria (e.g. keyword search) and then assign less weight to those results that have a date in the past but still meet the search criteria?  The illustration below should help to convey my needs:

#### Table containing data to be searched:

```
--------- ------------------ ---------
entry_id | title            | date    |
--------- ------------------ ---------
1         Tennis Racquet     12-10-2010
2         Basketball         03-24-2011
3         Tennis             03-03-2012
4         Skydiving          09-16-2012
5         Fishing            11-27-2012
6         Tennis Court       02-09-2013
```

#### Search Term:

```
tennis
```

#### Search Results:

1. Entry 3 - Tennis
2. Entry 6 - Tennis Court
3. Entry 1 - Tennis Racquet - This is returned last because the date of this entry is before today's date (2-9-2012), but it still matches the search term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a way to do this using a variation of @mobius' `SetSortMode` example.

Instead of using `SPH_SORT_EXTENDED`, I used `SPH_SORT_EXPR` along with the expression below:

```
$cl->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXPR, 
        " @weight + ( -1000000000/(" . time() . " - course_date_ts)) ");
```

This allows me to weigh upcoming results higher, then future results slightly lower, and finally old results last.

The large number in the numerator is to correspond with the number of decimal places in the UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

On your sphinx.conf you should specify the date as a timestamp in your select query as such:

```
SELECT entry_id, title, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date_timestamp FROM Table;
```

and specify that the date_timestamp column is of type timestamp by:

```
sql_attr_timestamp = date_timestamp
```

Now you can sort the results by the timestamp column. Check the Sorting section of the Sphinx manual http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes

i.e in PHP:

```
$search->SetSortMode( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@weight DESC, date_timestamp ASC );
```

Comment: yes, this allows me to sort by timestamp, but it does not allow me to rank the older listings lower than the current/future listings.  any suggestions?

Comment: @ServAce85 Ah. Now I understand. Perhaps the setFieldWeight() function will do what you want. Like: $search->setFieldWeight( array('date_timestamp' => 10) ); See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/api-func-setfieldweights.html

Comment: I think I've found a solution (listed below) using a modification of your first suggestion: `SPH_SORT_EXTENDED`.  Thanks for the help.